# cookie value in php dosen't change

Tags: php, cookies

I have a big problem in changing cookie value. I have buttom function to change(if exist)/create(if !exist) cookie and set value for it.

When i call function the session value changed, but not happened any change in cookie data.

```
function setToken($time = 0) {
  global $value;
  if (!isset($_COOKIE["name"])) {
    setcookie("name", $value, time() + $time);
  } else {
    $_COOKIE["name"] = $value;
  }
  $_SESSION["name"] = $value;
}
```

What's wrong && What's should i do???

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to
>   debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

**Update:**
Your code works for me. But make sure you give a positive integer to your function `setToken()`. If you do not, the cookie will be immediately expired and not be shown!

If you want to change the cookie value, change your code:

```
function setToken($time = 0) {
  global $value;
  if (!isset($_COOKIE["name"])) {
    setcookie("name", $value, time() + $time); // inital set
  } else {
    setcookie("name", $value); // change value
  }
  $_SESSION["name"] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I check it after several times loading page but not happened and it's value was the first.

Comment: thank for your attention. I change it and fix that problem. but yet cookie dosen't change

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to the `$_COOKIE` global doesn't actually set the cookie in the browser. Always call `setcookie`.

Also, make sure that no content has been sent to the browser before you set the cookie. Cookies are set in the headers sent to the browser so cannot be set after content has started to be flushed.

Comment: more explain please.